# Unable to sort NSMutableArray of Custom Objects

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I've got an issue trying to sort an array of custom objects. It's looking as if my arrays aren't even hitting the sorting code, but rather simply just returning the array itself.

I have the following setup:

```
SearchResult : NSObject
--
Document : SearchResult
Tag : SearchResult
Folder : SearchResult
```

My code is getting returns as `SearchResult`s then trying to compare them all with a key, `name` that is defined in the `SearchResult` implementation.

```
-(void) parseFolderContents:(NSDictionary *) data
{
NSMutableArray *searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *documents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *folders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *tags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *results = [data objectForKey:@"items"];
for (int i = 0; i < [results count]; i++)
{
    SearchResult *result = (SearchResult *)[KTParser parseSearchResult:[results objectAtIndex:i]];
    if ([result.type isEqualToString:@"document"]){
        [documents addObject:result];
    }
    else if ([result.type isEqualToString:@"folder"])
    {
        [folders addObject:result];
    }
    else if ([result.type isEqualToString:@"tag"])
    {
        [tags addObject:result];
    }
}
if ([documents count] > 0)
    [searchResults addObject:documents];
if ([folders count] > 0)
    [searchResults addObject:folders];
if ([tags count] > 0)
    [searchResults addObject:tags];

....
```

So that's the code used to populate the array, which isn't anything special. I have tried each of these ways to compare the array. None have worked. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

First attempt:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name"
                                             ascending:YES];    
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedResults;
sortedResults = [searchResults sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Second attempt:

```
NSArray *sortedResults;
sortedResults = [searchResults sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

(implementing custom compare method on SearchResult/Document.m)
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(SearchResult *)otherResult{
  return [self.name compare:otherResult.name];
}
```

Third attempt:

```
    sortedResults = (NSMutableArray *)[searchResults sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];
```

Fourth attempt I tried using a block. I even tried putting code in to manipulate the sorting of it, which didn't work either. The array returned was exactly the same as the original:

```
sortedArray = [searchResults sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    if ([(SearchResult *)a itemId] < 20000 )
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else
        return NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is `name` a public property defined in `SearchResult`?
Your code seems correct, so I suspect something could be wrong with the class definitions.

Comment: Yup, name is a public property defined! Just figured out the issue - I was doing `[searchResults addObject:documents]` instead of `addObjectsFromArray`. This was making searchResults hold arrays instead of actual objects, which is why none of the compare/sorting was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue - I was adding arrays as objects instead of adding each object into the array. This was then calling sort on NSArray, instead of my custom objects. Changing the above code from `[searchResults addObject:documents];` to `[searchResults addObjectsFromArray:documents];` solved the issue!